# Alternative way in (.on(input, function))

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am having a problem with this. My code is working fine but I use it to update then now I have a problem because value is already set.

In this code :

```js
    $('#principal').on('input', function() {
        calculate();
    });
    $('#interest').on('input', function() {
        calculate();
    });
```

it works when you input a value on a field. But what if I have this code :

```html
<input class="form-control number" name="principal" id="principal" type="text"  value="<?php print $fetch['principal']; ?>" required/>

<input class="form-control number" name="interest" id="interest" type="text" value="<?php print $fetch['interest']; ?>" required/>
```

Value is already set. What code should I use in JQUERY to execute the code without type or editing value from input field.

Sample Output: Edit the value of Principal (What I want is to run compute without clicking or editing something)

```js
    $('#principal, #interest').on('input', function() {
        calculate();
    });
    function calculate(){
        var principal = $('#principal').val();
        principal = principal.replace(/,/g, "");
        principal = parseInt(principal);
        var interest = $('#interest').val();
        interest = interest.replace(/,/g, "");
        interest = parseInt(interest);
        var total = "";
        var total_interest = "";
        if(isNaN(interest) || isNaN(principal)){
            total_interest = " ";
            total = " ";
            }
        else{
            total_interest = (interest / 100) * principal;
            total = (interest / 100) * principal + principal;
        }

        var num = total;
        num = addCommas(num);
        $('#total').val(num);

        var num_interest = total_interest;
        num_interest = addCommas(num_interest);
        $('#total_interest').val(num_interest);

        function addCommas(nStr) {
            nStr += '';
            x = nStr.split('.');
            x1 = x[0];
            x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
            var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
            while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
            }
            return x1 + x2;
        }
    }
    
        $('.number').keyup(function(event){

        // skip for arrow keys
        if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
      
        // format number
        $(this).val(function(index, value) {
          return value
          .replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Principal:
<input class="form-control number" name="principal" id="principal" type="text"  value="9000" required/>
<br><br>
Interest:
<input class="form-control number" name="interest" id="interest" type="text" value="10" required/>
<br><br>
Total Interest:
<input class="form-control number" name="total_interest" id="total_interest" type="text" readonly/>
<br><br>
Total Payment
<input class="form-control number" name="total" id="total" type="text" readonly/>
```

Comment: you can use on load

Comment: yes maybe onload fix your problem.

Comment: onload wont work too

Comment: @ArvinJasonCabrera - Yes, it would. It's not what I'd use, it happens too late, but it would work. You keep saying things don't work that do. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). Both my answer and the onload suggestion work based on what's in the question now.

Comment: Update provided :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
calculate();
```

...in code at the top level of your script. Make sure your script is at the end of `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Example:

```js
function calculate() {
  console.log(
    "calculating with " +
    $("#principal").val() +
    " and " +
    $("#interest").val()
  );
}

$('#principal').on('input', function() {
  calculate();
});
$('#interest').on('input', function() {
  calculate();
});

calculate();
```

```html
<input class="form-control number" name="principal" id="principal" type="text"  value="42" required/>
<input class="form-control number" name="interest" id="interest" type="text" value="3.7" required/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: You can simplify and consolidate your `on` calls:

```
$('#principal, #interest').on('input', calculate);
```

```js
function calculate() {
  console.log(
    "calculating with " +
    $("#principal").val() +
    " and " +
    $("#interest").val()
  );
}

$('#principal, #interest').on('input', calculate);

calculate();
```

```html
<input class="form-control number" name="principal" id="principal" type="text"  value="42" required/>
<input class="form-control number" name="interest" id="interest" type="text" value="3.7" required/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Here's the snippet you added to your answer, with

```
calculate();
```

...added to the end:

```js
$('#principal, #interest').on('input', function() {
        calculate();
    });
    function calculate(){
        var principal = $('#principal').val();
        principal = principal.replace(/,/g, "");
        principal = parseInt(principal);
        var interest = $('#interest').val();
        interest = interest.replace(/,/g, "");
        interest = parseInt(interest);
        var total = "";
        var total_interest = "";
        if(isNaN(interest) || isNaN(principal)){
            total_interest = " ";
            total = " ";
            }
        else{
            total_interest = (interest / 100) * principal;
            total = (interest / 100) * principal + principal;
        }

        var num = total;
        num = addCommas(num);
        $('#total').val(num);

        var num_interest = total_interest;
        num_interest = addCommas(num_interest);
        $('#total_interest').val(num_interest);

        function addCommas(nStr) {
            nStr += '';
            x = nStr.split('.');
            x1 = x[0];
            x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
            var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
            while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
            }
            return x1 + x2;
        }
    }
    
        $('.number').keyup(function(event){

        // skip for arrow keys
        if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
      
        // format number
        $(this).val(function(index, value) {
          return value
          .replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        });
    });
calculate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Principal:
<input class="form-control number" name="principal" id="principal" type="text"  value="9000" required/>
<br><br>
Interest:
<input class="form-control number" name="interest" id="interest" type="text" value="10" required/>
<br><br>
Total Interest:
<input class="form-control number" name="total_interest" id="total_interest" type="text" readonly/>
<br><br>
Total Payment
<input class="form-control number" name="total" id="total" type="text" readonly/>
```

Comment: Thanks sir but on input function wont work if value is already set.

Comment: I am trying to do is do calculate even i dont input anything

Comment: @ArvinJasonCabrera - That's why you call `calculate` directly, which is the whole point of the answer above. Run the runnable snippets. Note that they work. :-)

Comment: I have provided runable in snippet sir. Please take a look :)

Comment: @ArvinJasonCabrera - And if you add `calculate();` to the end, as I said in the answer, it works. I've added a copy of your snippet with that one extra line to the end of the answer.

Comment: @ArvinJasonCabrera - LOL.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the result from the server

so from PHP side do the calculate() method and just print it into the result field. as you did with the values, or after your code loaded from js.

or you can use jQuery trigger

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#principal').trigger('input');
    $('#interest').trigger('input');
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. please take a look for my udated questing